# How do I remove stuck on PETG filament from stock Ender 3 bed?

Tags: creality-ender-3, petg, bed

So I’m kind of a newbie to 3D printing. I got my Ender 3 about 3 days ago and some PETG filament to accompany it. These are the slicer settings:

- Hotend: 235 °C
- Initial bed temperature: 80 °C
- Bed temperature: 70 °C
- Layer height: 0.12 mm

I also use a brim on the outside of the prints. Every time I print, some of the bottom layers stick onto the bed. I’ve seen somewhere that if you heat it to 70 °C you can scrape it off, but that doesn’t work for me.

[image: Photo of a print bed with some of the bottom layers of a print stuck to the bed]

Comment: This reason for this to happen has been answered in other questions, see e.g. [this question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/14783). Your nozzle is probably too close to the bed. Furthermore, you could use a bed adhesive spray as a release agent, a common brand is 3DLAC, but there are many others.

Comment: In contrary to other plastics, PETG is generally sticking too well to the buildplate. I had good experiences by using a structured PEI spring steel build plate. It prevents making any mess with glue or other mentioned release agents.

Answer (score 2):

Spray all remainings with Isopropyl Alcohol and try rubbing it with a paper towel or sponge. Isopropyl Alcohol works as a [release agent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTRvBmta3Zs) in this case and it may also soften these residues a bit. Try gently scraping it with a scraper, but be careful not to damage the surface, since the stock magnetic beds are quite soft. Scraping it with a utility knife or razor blade is not recommended, because it may permanently destroy the print surface.

Try to heat the bed a bit more to 80 °C. Heating it above 80 °C is not recommended, as it may damage surface adhesion. After that, wash the surface with a sponge in warm water. You can repeat this process until you get satisfying effect.

If you print in these places, these remainings may stick to new prints and could disappear after some time. For future prints, follow [Oscar's advices](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/20371/how-do-i-remove-stuck-on-petg-filament-from-stock-ender-3-bed#comment38771_20371) to avoid similar issues.