# What are these defects caused by?

Tags: petg, anycubic-kobra-max

I am printing PETG with my Kobra Max.

Material: ERYONE PETG Filament 1.75 mm

The recommended print settings are 220-240 °C.

I am using a nozzle temperature of 230 °C and bed temperature of 70 °C.

Can anybody tell me what these defects are caused by?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your build-plate (print bed) is out-of-level. Specifically, your printer's nozzle is **too close** to the build plate as witnessed by the first layer being semi-translucent in some areas but not others; This indicates it's very thin.

The defect you see is parts of the first layer being 'peeled' up by the printhead as it moves by, as excess plastic has built up in those areas, causing the hot-end to smash into them and delaminate them as it attempts to print other parts of the part.

If you don't already know how to level/tram your bed, check out your printer's manual for instructions (if it has any) or read a [Bed-Levelling guide](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/474/6996)